# How to dynamically create component instance with input/output from a service and inject it to DOM separately?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

In creating dynamic components in Angular 2, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) [out](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/07/19/building-angular-2-components-on-the-fly-a-dialog-box-example/) that this process requires `ViewContainerRef` in order to add newly created component to DOM.

And in passing `@Input` and `@Output`to those dynamically created components, I found the answer in the second link above and [here](https://codedump.io/share/kQakwDKNu0iG/1/passing-input-while-creating-angular-2-component-dynamically-using-componentresolver).

However, if I were to create a service named `shape.service` that contains functions returning different shape components with some `@Input` like `bgColor`, I don't know how this service will create a component without specifying DOM location, and how the container-component receives this returned component (probably its type will be `ComponentRef`) from the service and injects it to the DOM container-component specifies.

For example, a service contains a method:

```
getCircle(bgColor:string): ComponentRef<Circle> {
    let circleFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CircleComponent);
    let circleCompRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(circleFactory);
    circleCompRef.instance.bgColor = bgColor;

    return circleCompRef;
}
```

First question rises here, how do I make `this.viewContainerRef` point to no where for the meantime? The reason why I'm importing `ViewContainerRef` is to create component dynamically.

Second question is after container-component receives input-specific`componentRef` from the service, how will it inject to its DOM?

**UPDATE:**
I think my question above wasn't specific enough. I'm in a situation where:

1. A parent component calls the service and gets the componentRef/s,
2. Creates an object including componentRef/s together with some other data and stores those created object/s into array
3. Passes it to its children as `@Input`,
4. And let each child inject componentRef to its DOM and use rest of the data in the object in other way.

That means the service calling component has no idea where those componentRef will get injected. In short, I need independent component objects that can be injected to anywhere, anytime I want.

I'm reading the rumTimeCompiler solution several times already but I don't really get how that really works. It seems like there's too much work compared to component creation using viewContainerRef. I'll dig into that more if I find no other solution...

Comment: *NOTE: also check solution with `RuntimeCompiler` http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310*

Answer (score 12):

In case someone like me still looking for a simple and clear solution nowdays - here it is. I got it from @angular/cdk https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/cdk
and made a simple service.

```js
import {
    Injectable,
    ApplicationRef,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ComponentRef,
    Injector,
    EmbeddedViewRef
} from '@angular/core';

export type ComponentType<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

    constructor(
        private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
        private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private _injector: Injector
    ) { }

    private _components: ComponentRef<any>[] = [];

    add<T>(
        component: ComponentType<T> | ComponentRef<T>,
        element?: Element | string
    ): ComponentRef<T> {
        const componentRef = component instanceof ComponentRef
            ? component
            : this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component).create(this._injector);
        this._appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
        if (typeof element === 'string') {
            element = document.querySelector(element);
        }
        if (!element) {
            element = document.body;
        }
        element.appendChild(
            (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement
        );
        this._components.push(componentRef);
        return componentRef;
    }

    remove(dialog: number | ComponentRef<any>): boolean {
        let componentRef;
        if (typeof dialog === 'number' && this._components.length > dialog)  {
            componentRef = this._components.splice(dialog, 1)[0];
        }
        else {
            for (const cr of this._components) {
                if (cr === dialog) {
                    componentRef = cr;
                }
            }
        }
        if (componentRef) {
            this._remove(componentRef);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private _remove(componentRef: ComponentRef<any>) {
        this._appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
        componentRef.destroy();
    }

    clear() {
        while (this._components.length > 0) {
            this._remove(this._components.pop());
        }
    }

    getIndex(componentRef: ComponentRef<any>): number {
        return this._components.indexOf(componentRef);
    }

}
```

You can pass ComponentClass or ComponentRef to `add` and Element or any querySelector string pointing to any DOM element where you want to attach your component as second argument (or nothing, then it assumes you want to attach to body).

```js
const cr = this._service.add(MyComponent); // will create MyComponent and attach it to document.body or
const cr = this._service.add(MyComponent, this.someElement); // to attach to Element stored in this.someElement or
const cr = this._service.add(MyComponent, 'body div.my-class > div.my-other-div'); // to search for that element and attach to it
const crIndex = this._service.getIndex(cr);
cr.instance.myInputProperty = 42;
cr.instance.myOutputEmitter.subscribe(
    () => {
        // do something then for example remove this component
        this._service.remove(cr);
    }
);
this._service.remove(crIndex); // remove by index or
this._service.remove(cr); // remove by reference or
this._service.clear(); // remove all dynamically created components
```

**P.S. Don't forget** to add your dynamic components to `entryComponents: []` of `@NgModule`

Comment: Works perfectly but I had to do some tweaking, btw I'm using Angular 9:


* Injecting `private appRef: ApplicationRef` directly in the constructor caused a cyclic dependency error: `Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef`, so I opted for the lazy loading of the object using the injector 


```
this.appRef = this.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
```


* Also when calling the add element you can attach it to a dom object identified by id using:


`this._service.add(MyComponent, '#my-element-id');`

Comment: Yeah works nicely. Really many thanks!
Not sure about the entryComponents[] since I could use this without setting it.

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` is now deprecated :(

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this plunker will help you: https://plnkr.co/edit/iTG7Ysjuv7oiDozuXwj6?p=preview

As far as i know, you will need the `ViewContainerRef` inside of your service.
But the component calling your service can add it as an parameter, like this:

(just a the service.. see plunker for full working example)

```
import { Injectable, ViewContainerRef, ReflectiveInjector, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';

import { HelloComponent, HelloModel } from './hello.component';

@Injectable()
export class DynamicCompService {

  constructor (private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  public createHelloComp (vCref: ViewContainerRef, modelInput: HelloModel): ComponentRef {

    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);

    // vCref is needed cause of that injector..
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], vCref.parentInjector);

    // create component without adding it directly to the DOM
    let comp = factory.create(injector);

    // add inputs first !! otherwise component/template crashes ..
    comp.instance.model = modelInput;

    // all inputs set? add it to the DOM ..
    vCref.insert(comp.hostView);

    return comp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I pressed enter before finishing my sentence :( Sorry for removing the "green check" on your answer. I thought this was what I needed but I found out my question wasn't specific enough... Do you mind checking the update and giving another solution if possible? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: I dont know if its possible to create a component just like that way, cause the component needs to know which components, services and directives it could use..i am currently searching for a solution, too. maybe we will found something .. keep this thread up! :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I still have no idea why it is not possible to create component instance without specifying its viewContainer. If that's possible, I believe it'll be easier to move, delete, or add existing component instance easily from one container to another. It's somehow possible to do with componentFactory but it becomes hard to implement if that component requires input/output. I tried to look for why it is a "must" to specify viewcontainer in creating component instance, but I still don't know why. I hope someone would at least give an answer to that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach to adding a component dynamically and managing communication between that component and its parent.

The specific example is for a dialog box with a form, which is a common use case.

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack).

[Repo with code](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack)

- `dialog-wrapper` is a dialog component
- `dialog-form` is an example of a dynamic component being injected into `dialog-wrapper`, with the necessary supporting services.
- `name` (Alice) is an example of arbitrary data being passed from the parent component to `dialog-form` via `dialog-wrapper`
- An object with `name` and `favouriteFood` is then passed back to the parent when the form in `dialog-form` is submitted. This also tiggers the parent component to close `dialog-wrapper`.

I've tried to keep the code as straightforward as possible so it can be easily retasked. The [dialog wrapper](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/dialog-wrapper/dialog-wrapper.component.ts) itself is fairly simple; most of the heavy lifting is in the [injected component](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/dialog-form/dialog-form.component.ts) and the [parent component](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts).

This is not exactly the architecture outlined in the OP, but I believe it satisfies:

> I need independent component objects that can be injected to anywhere, anytime I want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was looking for a solution without using [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) that is now deprecated:

> Deprecated: Angular no longer requires Component factories. Please use other APIs where Component class can be used directly.

And I found this solution from a colleague of mine by using [createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent) instead.